# I want Pause and Resume for this jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout("wave()", 0);
});

function wave(){
$("#wave1")
    .animate({left:"100px", top:"400px" },2000) 
    .animate({left:"200px", top:"0px" },2000) 
    .animate({left:"300px", top:"400px" },2000) 
    .animate({left:"400px", top:"0px" },2000) 
    .animate({left:"500px", top:"400px" },2000) 
    .animate({left:"600px", top:"0px" },2000) 
    .animate({left:"500px", top:"400px" },2000) 
    .animate({left:"400px", top:"0px" },2000) 
    setTimeout("wave()")
}
```

Is there a way I could somehow Pause/Resume my animation in jQuery?

Comment: Please read the FAQ and fix the formatting of your question.

Comment: And I want a pony. I'll answer your question if you send me one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation